# Meaning of: supplementalGroups: [ 65534 ]?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I am looking at this yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kube-dns-autoscaler
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns-autoscaler
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kube-dns-autoscaler
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-dns-autoscaler
    spec:
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
      securityContext:
        seccompProfile:
          type: RuntimeDefault
        supplementalGroups: [ 65534 ]
        fsGroup: 65534
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      containers:
      - name: autoscaler
        image: k8s.gcr.io/cpa/cluster-proportional-autoscaler:1.8.4
        resources:
            requests:
                cpu: "20m"
                memory: "10Mi"
        command:
          - /cluster-proportional-autoscaler
          - --namespace=kube-system
          - --configmap=kube-dns-autoscaler
          # Should keep target in sync with cluster/addons/dns/kube-dns.yaml.base
          - --target=<SCALE_TARGET>
          # When cluster is using large nodes(with more cores), "coresPerReplica" should dominate.
          # If using small nodes, "nodesPerReplica" should dominate.
          - --default-params={"linear":{"coresPerReplica":256,"nodesPerReplica":16,"preventSinglePointFailure":true,"includeUnschedulableNodes":true}}
          - --logtostderr=true
          - --v=2
```

Source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-horizontal-autoscaling/#enablng-dns-horizontal-autoscaling

Where can I find the documentation for these magic numbers?

```
        supplementalGroups: [ 65534 ]
        fsGroup: 65534
```

Comment: I found a very similar question about [fsGroup and supplementalGroups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69805813/fsgroup-vs-supplementalgroups) will it be useful to you?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak this question/answer does not help me much. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find the documentation for these magic numbers?

It comes from Users, Groups, UIDs and GIDs on systemd Systems. Here you can work with different parameters  and also ranges more info about [`systems` UID/GID.](https://systemd.io/UIDS-GIDS/)

Special Linux UIDs
In theory, the range of the C type  `uid_t`  is 32bit wide on Linux, i.e. 0…4294967295. However, four UIDs are special on Linux:

1. 0 → The  `root`  super-user
2. 65534 → The  `nobody`  UID, also called the “overflow” UID or similar. It’s where various subsystems map unmappable users to, for example file systems only supporting 16bit UIDs, NFS or user namespacing. (The latter can be changed with a sysctl during runtime, but that’s not supported on  `systemd`. If you do change it you void your warranty.) Because Fedora is a bit confused the  `nobody`  user is called  `nfsnobody`  there (and they have a different  `nobody`  user at UID 99). I hope this will be corrected eventually though. (Also, some distributions call the  `nobody`  group  `nogroup`. I wish they didn’t.)
3. 4294967295, aka “32bit  `(uid_t) -1`” → This UID is not a valid user ID, as  `setresuid()`,  `chown()`  and friends treat -1 as a special request to not change the UID of the process/file. This UID is hence not available for assignment to users in the user database.
4. 65535, aka “16bit  `(uid_t) -1`” → Before Linux kernel 2.4  `uid_t`  used to be 16bit, and programs compiled for that would hence assume that  `(uid_t) -1`  is 65535. This UID is hence not usable either.

> **Well, we have parameters in Kubernetes and let's describe what it is:**

[**SupplementalGroups**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#users-and-groups)   - Controls which group IDs containers add.

- *MustRunAs*  - Requires at least one  `range`  to be specified. Uses the minimum value of the first range as the default. Validates against all ranges.
- *MayRunAs*  - Requires at least one  `range`  to be specified. Allows  `supplementalGroups`  to be left unset without providing a default. Validates against all ranges if  `supplementalGroups`  is set.
- *RunAsAny*  - No default provided. Allows any  `supplementalGroups`  to be specified.

[**FSGroup**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#volumes-and-file-systems)  - Controls the supplemental group applied to some volumes.

- *MustRunAs*  - Requires at least one  `range`  to be specified. Uses the minimum value of the first range as the default. Validates against all ranges.
- *MayRunAs*  - Requires at least one  `range`  to be specified. Allows  `FSGroups`  to be left unset without providing a default. Validates against all ranges if  `FSGroups`  is set.
- *RunAsAny*  - No default provided. Allows any  `fsGroup`  ID to be specified.